# CSS - Bootstrap Menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap with Hyde CSS and I am having difficult doing the following:

Where the icon (image) is in the menu, I want to display the text right next to it, but I can't seem to figure out how to do with using the

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Here is what I currently have:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="home2">
      <a href="/">
       <img class="first" src="/images/home-icon.png">
       Home
      </a>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Which is producing the following:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the styles on the image? I believe images are by default `display: block`. If you want the image to be to the left of the text, either give the image `float: left` or `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the comment made by Aeolingamenfel is right. I made a sample in jsfiddle where you can see the display in action.

[JSFiddle Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/jurandirvalerio/6cg00yg9/3/)

```
<style>
    .homeWrong > a > img{
      display: block;
    }

    .homeRight > a > img{
      display: inline;
    }
</style>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="homeWrong">
       <a href="/">
        <img class="first" src="/images/home-icon.png">
        Home
        </a>
     </li>
     <li class="homeRight">
      <a href="/">
       <img class="first" src="/images/home-icon.png">
       Home
      </a>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. Just use this css below:

```
.home2 img{
     display:inline-block;
     vertical-align:middle; //You can use the exact amount like ..px;
}
```